# Get fkey button: see your chat fkey without inspecting the source!

Tags: script, chat

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

#### Userscript

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Get fkey
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Get your Stack Exchange chat fkey
// @author       PlaceReporter99
// @match        https://chat.stackexchange.com/**
// @match        https://chat.stackoverflow.com/**
// @match        https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/**
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=stackexchange.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("get fkey"));
    button.setAttribute("class", "button");
    button.setAttribute("onclick", "alert(document.getElementById('fkey').getAttribute('value'));");
    document.getElementById("chat-buttons").appendChild(button);

})();
```

#### Bookmarklet

```js
javascript:(function(){'use strict';const button=document.createElement("button");button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("get fkey"));button.setAttribute("class","button");button.setAttribute("onclick","alert(document.getElementById('fkey').getAttribute('value'));");document.getElementById("chat-buttons").appendChild(button)})();
```

### About

This Tampermonkey userscript adds a button to your user interface, that appears even when you are suspended. When clicked, it shows your fkey in an alert dialog.

#### License

No license yet.

#### Download

The GitHub Gist for the userscript is [here](https://gist.github.com/PlaceReporter99/dc95781c7373b0dc86a07b22eb304d19).

#### Platform

Tested with Tampermonkey on Chrome.

### Contact

I created this script, and I am currently the only contributor. You can message me in Stack Exchange chat. Remember to ping me with `@TheEmptyStringPhotographer`.

### Code

This runs on Tampermonkey, and the code is in [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/PlaceReporter99/dc95781c7373b0dc86a07b22eb304d19). You can leave a suggestion by posting an answer here, or a comment on the Gist.